# Mongodb connection retry

Tags: go, mongodb

Created a MongoDB client which is handling the retry in case of server connection failure. Please review and how I can improve further.

```
package db

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "time"
    

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/event"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

const SupplyReportDB = "abc"
const SupplyAlertsCollection = "abc"

type MongoDB struct {
    client *mongo.Client
    uri    string
}

func NewMongoDBCon(context context.Context, uri string) (*MongoDB, error) {
    var conn = &MongoDB{uri: uri}
    client, err := conn.Connect(context)
    if err != nil {
        return conn, err
    }
    conn.client = client
    return conn, err
}

func (m *MongoDB) Connect(context context.Context) (*mongo.Client, error) {
    serverMonitor := &event.ServerMonitor{
        ServerHeartbeatFailed: m.serverHandler,         
    }

    client, err := mongo.Connect(
        context, options.Client().
            ApplyURI(m.uri).
            SetHeartbeatInterval(5*time.Second).
            SetServerMonitor(serverMonitor),
    )

    if err != nil {
        return client, err
    }

    if err := client.Ping(context, nil); err != nil {
        return client, errors.New("not connected")
    }
    return client, nil
}

func (m *MongoDB) Close(context context.Context) error {
    if err := m.client.Disconnect(context); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *MongoDB) GetSupplyAlertCollection() *mongo.Collection {
    collection := m.client.Database(SupplyReportDB).Collection(SupplyAlertsCollection)
    return collection
}

func (m *MongoDB) reconnect() {
    count := 1
    for {
        if count == 3{
            log.Fatal("Problem in connecting MongoDB.. exiting..")
        }
        log.Println("Retrying for the ", count, "time")
        client, err := m.Connect(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
        } else {
            log.Println("Reconnected successfully.")
            m.client = client
            break
        }
        count++
    }
}

func (m *MongoDB)serverHandler(evt *event.ServerHeartbeatFailedEvent) {
    m.reconnect()   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think about replacing the "for loop" with a retry package https://github.com/avast/retry-go. Should be a little bit cleaner.

```
func (m *MongoDB) reconnect() {
err := retry.Do(func() error {
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), m.uri, mongo.ConnectTimeout(5*time.Second))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to MongoDB at %s: %s", m.uri, err)
        return err
    }
    log.Println("Reconnected successfully.")
    m.client = client
    return nil
},
    retry.Attempts(3),
    retry.Delay(4*time.Second),
    retry.OnRetry(func(n uint, err error) {
        log.Printf("Retry %d: %s", n, err)
    }),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Problem in connecting MongoDB.. exiting..")
}}
```

Also using exponential backoff (in the delay) could be an option.